# Qt(necessitas) + SDL + Android

Tags: android, qt, android-ndk, sdl

I've written an application ([an open source ROV controller](http://sourceforge.net/p/rov-suite/)) in Qt that uses SDL for joystick support on Windows and OSX and I'd like to port it to Android.  My only issue is that I need to get USB joystick support in Android.  Has anybody gotten SDL to work with Qt **on Android**?  If so, how did you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gotten several somewhat complex programs based on the SDL 1.2 library to work on Android.  The code base for that is here -

http://github.com/pelya/commandergenius

Pelya's port of SDL 1.2 to Android has support for joystick controls (which it can mimic on-screen, and which you can extend).  I have done experimental ports that use the joystick, although none of my releases yet have utilized that feature.

As far as qt, the qt lighthouse project for Android is codenamed necessitas, and is located here http://sourceforge.net/p/necessitas/home/necessitas .  I don't know firsthand how far along their port is, but their project is your best bet.

Comment: Thanks for the information and the links, Dennis!  I'm trying to compile my application using Necessitas, and it's getting further along than it used to, but now I seem to run into an error with linking to an external library (when compiling my application I get "undefined reference to `SDL_JoystickNumButtons'" errors).  How can I compile the SDL shared object to link to so that I can compile my application?

Comment: I have a port of Circuslinux which uses SDL 1.2 to Android, and Circuslinux was a very simple port for an actual program.  Linking to SDL with pelya's port, it can handle calls to SDL_JoystickNumButtons -  http://github.com/dennis-sheil/commandergenius/blob/circuslinux/project/jni/application/circuslinux/circuslinux/circuslinux.c#L2864

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I got it working for the most part.  During runtime, it fails to detect my USB joystick and it can't seem to read the values of the axes of my accelerometer (which it can get both its name and number of axes).